# How CPU talk to GPU?

Tags: python, numpy, gpu, cpu

I run Keras code (tensorflow backend) on GPU

I simply run it without setting anything the code is run on GPU

automatically and I can see the usage of GPU

When I run my normal python code and I check my

usage of GPU ,it turns out to be 0%.

My questions are:

(1) How to make CPU send the data to GPU and always let GPU compute it.

(2)I heard that the default of numpy array data type is always set to "float" ,Does is have something to do with GPU?

Comment: Keras has a limited computational model and therefore it allows fully automatic GPU calculation using those assumptions (which includes graphic driver usage, their HW-near APIs and probably compilation). Running just any code on GPU is not possible in general and even if there is a full CPU -> GPU compiler, it would be useless for 99.9% of all inputs (GPUs are not great at everything). Numpy's defaults have nothing to do with GPU. numpy does not know anything about the existence of GPUs,

Comment: @sascha Thanks!  So how do computer activate the graphic card (gpu )while playing game?